# How to extract properties data from a profile in a parent pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have a big Java project and each sub-part of the project has a child pom.xml. The parent pom has key data I want, username and password. My question is how can I extract this data from a parent pom.xml in my java program?

The parent pom.xml has numerous profiles in the profile section where the data is that I need. I found a similar example that said to simply code `System.getProperty('property.name');` When I tried this the code just returned null though. I think it is because I ran the code from the `target` directory and not through Maven, but I could be completely wrong about this.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a build tool (and much more). Your program does not know its existence. The example you probably refer to, uses some system property which is available to both maven and your code.
You can refer to system properties in maven. Its easy.

see [reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html)

> Any property which can be retrieved from the System.getProperty()
>   method can be referenced as a Maven property.

Comment: Thank-you for the information @grid. :) This helped some but I am still completely confused how to extract the data from the parent pom.xml. :/

Comment: If I understood what you try to do is to access pom variables from code. This is not possible and for a reason. The maven variables are there to provide customization to the build. After the build is over they have no meaning.

Comment: Oh noooooooooooooooooooooo. :/ I will have to think of something else. Thanks for supplying that critical information.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would clearly oppose the one that @grid suggested. Although *Maven* is a build tool, but it is also such a goodness that it can afford any functionality when you deeply think about it.

There was once a time where I needed to hook a custom properties file and ask Maven to filter it with *project properties* then read input that file content within the source code as a [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html]).

Now that part is over I suppose, since all the burden is done for you by the [*Properties Maven Plugin*](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) which has a cutom goal, "*set-system-properties*", that can make **project properties** (those used in by *Maven* and which are said to be build-time properties) available as runtime-properties and more precisely as **System Properties**.

You can add a custom plugin configuration snippet within your build section, the one in your **child** project, that may look as follows:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>property.name</name>
                  <value>${project.version}</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Although you can have any value set to your property, note the usage of the placeholder `${...}` so that *Maven* resolves the property when the project descriptors are interpolated. You can the reference any property such a way, then have it available at runtime as you suggested in your main post:

```java
package com.github.tmarwen.stackoverflow.maven.properties.showcase;

public Main {
  public static void main( String... args ) {
    String value = System.getProperty( "property.name" );
    System.out.print( value );
  }
}
```

Comment: Although that indeed is possible to extract maven properties as system properties, it does not mean that they should be used to feed the application. The deployable is then dependent on the build context. Unless you always run the application in the same JVM following a build, these properties will not exist at runtime. Think the case where you run CI builds and then deploy elsewhere.  Your properties simply won’t exist there.

Comment: I have absolutely thought of almost every target environment. Despite my answer is not entitled to be a production target but rather answers the user needs.